# Slowly implementing redux to an existing React.js project

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux-form

I want to migrate my project from plain react to react redux, I am not new to React but new to Redux. 
I have a fairly big web app written in React, dozens of React.js files.
most of them containing state's + passing variables between them.
including allot of Post/Get requests functions, implemented into at least half of my files.

I want to slowly move from plain react to react redux.

I wanted to ask if anyone have some article or can give an insight about migrating existing react project to react-redux.
I dont want to stop development for the sole purpose of the change but instead to slowly adapt to it.

is it possible ? is there a tool to help me do it ?

I saw some redux examples where entire render of app.js was surrounded by `<Provider> </Provider>`, does that mean every component inside `<Provider>` bracelet can not have it's own state ?
can I simply keep my old components as they are and put new ones into `<Provider> </Provider>` ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your question got answered, please pick the right answer, it will help others too.

Comment: I followed instructions in: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93p3LxR9xfM&t=1816s this video and managed to add it to the project. I surround entire project in provider and when I have a shared component I move it to store. I do it gradually and only for what is needed.

Answer (score 2):

> I saw some redux examples where entire render of app.js was surrounded
>   by  , does that mean every component inside
>    bracelet can not have it's own state ?

The way `react-redux` works is by exposing a `store` prop, provided by the `Provider`. In order to consume it, or extract data from it you must wrap your component by it (not directly necessarily, but one of the parents must be a provider). In general in most apps you would simply wrap the entire application with a `Provider`, because for the most part, if you've chosen to introduce `redux` into your application, it is probably because your entire app needs some store.
Using `redux` does not mean that components can't have state. There is a big difference between global state - something that should be accessible to every component in your app (if the component chooses to "consume" it), and state that is private to a component - e.g. form changes before being sent to the server.

> can I simply keep my old components as they are and put new ones into   ?

Well, yes. But also - no. As I said earlier, you should probably start from the top and slowly drill down. Wrap your app with a `Provider`, and start moving your application state from the top-most component to the store. Once you get more comfortable with `redux` in general, you should start replacing the props you pass down the component tree with props from the state by [connecting](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) your inner components.

This way you can do it one component at a time without breaking existing logic.

Comment: thanks for the explanation :), is there something stopping me from surrounding my entire application in ```<provider>``` and slowly move shared states to be global states in the store ?

Comment: It really depends on the specific way you designed your application, but there shouldn't be any obstacles going this way.